# Puppeteer download embedded PDF file

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chromium

I am visiting a page which has a link for a pdf file. The link opens a new tab and its content look like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);">
    <embed name="B4133D167D3B030DC294D8CA8F6FC5FE" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="B4133D167D3B030DC294D8CA8F6FC5FE">
  </body>
</html>
```

Embedded is the pdf I would like to download.

The only solution I have come up so far is manually changing the default behavior in `chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments` to download the PDF, but every time I restart the browser, it resets. Plus, I can't test this solution on headless mode...

I tried launching chromium with the `--print-to-pdf` flag found in this [list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), with no luck.

Does anyone know, if puppeteer can launch chromium with the "download PDF" as the default behavior, without tying it to a profile?

Does anyone know if there is another solution for puppeteer to download embedded pdfs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got to a solution that does the job for now using a chrome profile.

I created a new profile in my browser. I set the downloads directory and the default behavior for PDFs to "download PDFs".

I created a new folder somewhere for chromium to use as its data directory.

I pasted the previously created profile folder named 'Profile 2' inside the newly created folder.

Then on puppeteer I launched chromium with the following flags:

`--user-data-dir=newly_created_folder`
`--profile-directory=Profile 2`

I had to set both because when chromium first starts, it populates the user dir with its own files.

Every time the browser restarts, the file `SingletonLock` that sits on the 'user-data-dir' foder has to be overwritten. I ended up deleting the file before every execution of `puppeteer.launch(options)`.

For this to work on headless mode I set the parameter `headless: 'chrome'` and not true.

This works on puppeteer 17 and 18. I have tested it also in versions 14,15 and 16 with no luck.

Still, if anyone knows a better solution to download embedded PDFs, please share..

Thanks